Книги по fetch API
Поделитесь списком литературы в которой содержится инфо по Fetch API JavaScript.

Достаточно просто доки посмотреть. Там всё оченб подробно описано

По факту FetchAPI слишком мал что-бы так или иначе его описывать в книге. Всё описание умещается на паре страниц в MozDev, которые можно распечатать на принтере для изучения Offline.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Вот по сути и весь пример его использования в сложной ситуации
// Пример отправки POST запроса:
async function postData(url = "", data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return await response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

postData("https://example.com/answer", { answer: 42 }).then((data) => {
  console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
});

К данному с MozDEV примеру ещё дополнительно скажу. FetchAPI не отсылает название заголовков с заглавными буквами. То-есть если в headers указать Content-Type то на сервер всё равно будет отправлено content-type потому что Fetch работает в новых стандартах, где указанно что заголовки должны быть в lower-case. У нас в проекте были с этим проблемы в связке с Spring Web - пружинка не понимал authentication в lower-case, и пришлось вернуться к легаси XMLHttpRequest.
Исправленный баг: Спасибо Алексею за разъяснение.

"не отсылает название заголовков с заглавными буквами" --- это неправда............ ...... "У нас в проекте были с этим проблемы" --- вот проблема именно в серверной части, которая некорректно обрабатывает заголовки. Например у нас yii2 (тоже по-своему работает)

Правда. Хотя возможно что исправили... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656412/fetch-sends-lower-case-header-keys

Это был баг, который пофиксили ещё в 2017))  Там даже ссылка есть на issue....... сейчас всё работает  https://i.sstatic.net/fw3f9.png

Спасибо, Алексей. Буду знать.
